# jQuery fadeIn(), fadeOut() 2 texts

Tags: jquery, text, fadein, fadeout

How I can change 2 texts with fadeIn() and fadeOut() jQuery effects?

Here is an example: [Apple website](http://apple.com/).
Below the iPhone image is one box, "**Hot News Headlines**". See how the news changes? One text fades in, then fades out, and the second is coming.

I'm new to jQuery so please give detailed code. Thanks!

Comment: You maybe new to jq but at least show some commitment and let us see what you have already tried....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that your html is like this:

```
<div>
    <div class='fadey'>1</div>
    <div class='fadey'>2</div>
    <div class='fadey'>3</div>
</div>
```

You can do something like:

```
var faderIndex = 0, //to keep track
    faders = $('.fadey'); //cache, so we won't have to walk the dom every time

function nextFade() {

    //fade out element over 1000 milliseconds, after which call a function
    $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeOut(1000, function() {

        //increase the index and do a check, so we won't overflow
        faderIndex++;
        if (faderIndex >= faders.length)
            faderIndex = 0;

        //fade in the next element, after which call yourself infinitely
        $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeIn(1000, nextFade);
    });
}
//get the ball rolling
nextFade();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/gpQYW/

Comment: This is nice, I've been trying to adapt this example to work with a 'prev' and 'next' button scenario. I'm trying to adapt the nextFade function to do the reverse. Please could you take a quick look at my fiddle and let me know why the prev button isn't working very well, thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/gpQYW/441/

Comment: @H2ONOCK in `prevFade`, the condition for re-setting the `faderIndex` is that it's less than 0. In addition to that, the last index is not `faders.length`, but `faders.length-1`. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gpQYW/442/)

Comment: Brilliant, for anyone that is interested here is my finished working example (I've added a little bit in so that the functions cannot be called until after the current animation has finished): http://jsfiddle.net/gpQYW/443/

Answer (score 1):

Consider following HTML:

```
<span class="rotateText">Test</span>
<div class="rotateArray">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google.com</a>
    <a href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft.com</a>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow.com</a>
    <a href="http://www.wired.com">Wired.com</a>
</div>
```

and the script:

```
   $(function () {
        // set first
        $('.rotateText').html($('.rotateArray a').eq(0));
        // enter loop
        rotateText();
    });

    function rotateText() {         
        var count = $('.rotateArray a').length;
        var i = 0;
        var loopArr = $('.rotateArray a');
        var rotationElm = $('.rotateText');
        window.setInterval(function () {
            rotationElm
                    .fadeOut(400)
                    .queue(function () {
                        $(this).html('<a href="' + loopArr.eq(i).attr('href') + '">' + loopArr.eq(i).text() + '</a>');
                        if (++i == count) i = 0;                           
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    })
                    .fadeIn(400)
                    ;
        }, 4000);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the callback of the `.fadeOut()` function to change the HTML and *then* fade it in, as there will be flicker in the middle:

```
$('#foo').fadeOut(500, function() {
  $(this).html('<span>Bar</span>');
  $(this).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: I don't know jQuery, just seperate elements... So how will be the code for the fadedOut text?

Thanks previously!

Comment: That's in the serverside, not JavaScript. A PHP script, let's say, does that and jQuery animates it.

Comment: I don't need it dynamic i want 5 sentences in html like in the Apple website in <ul> tag see the source code...

Comment: That's generated via server. But I'll do a static one too.

Comment: THANKS Blender! It's perfect!